# Can't connect to updated SSMS version

Tags: sql-server, ssms, version

I recently downloaded the newest version of SSMS. It's installed successfully because when I open SSMS in my PC when I go into Tools > Check for Updates it says I am up to date.

[image]

However when I run the query select @@version it says I'm connected to the previous version I have. Does someone know how to connect to the latest version I installed?

Comment: You don't connect to SSMS, you connect to SQL Server. Updating your version of SSMS has no effect on the version of SQL Server; they are completely separate applications.

Comment: Larnu is correct. To clarify further, SSMS is just an application, or front-end interface that accesses SQL Server, which is installed on a central machine that clients, like yourself, connect to.

Comment: That makes more sense, I downloaded SQL 2019 and it resolved my issue. Thanks for the help.